# How to use an auto-incrementing integer in Python logger?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, logging

I want to use step number in my Python script. This step number should be auto incrementing and I want to put it as part of logger. Is there any default option available for that?

Comment: A code snippet would assist illustrating in your scenario & requirement.

Comment: I have something like this below: 
logger.info("Step %s : print hi" %step)
step+=1
logger.info("Step %s: print hello" %step)
step+=1

I want the step to be embedded in the logger, so that I dont have to increment it each time and can use it globally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to just wrap the logging call.

```
def step_log(message, *args, **kwargs):
  logging.info("Step %d:" % step_log.counter + message, *args, **kwargs)
  step_log.counter += 1
step_log.counter = 1
```

Comment: Thank you. That could work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This  could work in your case

`

```
step = 0

def sync_step():
    global step
    step = step+1

logging.info("message", sync_step())
logging.info("message", sync_step())
logging.info("message", sync_step())

print step # answer 3
```

`

Comment: Thank you. I could use this as well.

Comment: you could accept the answer that you find helpful.